# L'expression familière "être de" + événement auquel on est invité - régionalisme ou pas ?

Tags: expressions, régionalismes

J'ai entendu quelques fois en France l'expression familière "être de" signifiant "être invité à, avoir prévu d'assister à", utilisé avec le nom d'un événement tel un mariage, un anniversaire, un baptème, etc. Par exemple:

> > Tu viens boire un verre avec nous samedi ?
> >
> > -Ah non, désolé, je ne peux pas: je suis de mariage

Ou

> > Je dois y aller: je suis de baptème, et je dois encore changer de tenue.

Je me demande quelle est l'étendue géographique de cette expression...

Je viens de Belgique, et n'avais jamais entendu cette expression avant. Est-ce un régionalisme, peut-être du Sud de la France ?

Comment: Ma femme (de l'Oise en Picardie) vient de me dire qu'elle connait cet usage (argotique, d'après elle) mais ne pourrait pas dire si c'est un régionalisme. Elle pense que **peut-être** ça joue sur l'expression "être de garde" (i.e.,"Sorry, I can't make it, I'm on call this weekend [to fulfill some annoying family duty]).

Comment: Connu aussi en Bretagne, en Région parisienne et dans le Midi, un peu partout quoi. Je pense aussi à une origine militaire : *être de garde*, *être d'astreinte*, *être de quart*, *être de semaine*, *être de service* et les plus rares *être de paillasse*, *être de planton*.

Comment: On peut dire « être de la partie » mais il ne semble pas qu'autre chose de la sorte soit dit que l'on puisse considérer comme appartenant à la langue standard; on entend les formes telles que « de mariage » non pas dans les endroits où l'argot s'impose, mais plutôt dans les campagnes.

Comment: @user168676 Où sont-ils « les endroits où l'argot s'impose » dont vous parlez ?

Comment: @Papa Poule Well, if it is not in the country, we're lelft with cities and urban areas, those having to me always seemed to be the privileged breeding grounds of that particular "genre", if we might talk of genre; I must add that it might not be exact to make a clear-cut difference between those two as I seem to be doing; I could be reasonning a little too much in the past, and given that nowadays the media have more influence on the country part of the nation while they are much more free with the language they tolerate, the non city areas are, at least as recipients, catching up with argot.

Comment: Jamais entendu ça non plus, à part dans "être de corvée" (je suis aussi belge). Au vu des réponses, je serais assez confortable pour l'appeler un régionalisme français, à moins que ce ne soit aussi usité en Suisse et au Canada

Comment: Attention, "confortable" est un anglicisme. Une chaise peut être confortable, une personne est "à l'aise".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne pense pas que ca soit un régionalisme (l'ayant entendu dans pratiquement dans toutes les provinces sauf malheureusement celles adjacentes à la Belgique...).  Par contre c'est une expression d'origine militaire qui implique une corvée.

L'enthousiaste dirait 'je vais au mariage de ma petite sœur la semaine prochaine !'.  Mais si quelqu'un dit lourdement 'j'irais bien jouer à la pétanque avec mes potes ce weekend, mais je suis de mariage en Bretagne' l'implication est qu'il s'agit d'un mariage inintéressant, de gens dont on se moque bien, dont la famille est insupportable, et où même le gateau sera immangeable...

Comment: Merci - il y a donc bien une nuance similaire à celle de l'expression "je suis de corvée".

Comment: Que veut dire "dans toutes les provinces"? Des provinces françaises?

Answer (score 1):

Le Wiktionaire liste cet usage comme un usage normal, une des expressions possible pour "être de...."

> Être invité, ou s'être engagé, à participer, assister, à un événement (avec parfois une notion de contrainte, ou de promesse qu’on ne peut annuler).
>   Pino, tel une ombre, était de toutes les fêtes, de toutes les virées, de tous les bals en plein air préludant au troussement des filles moins farouches depuis l'invention de la pilule. (...)
>   Ah, non, désolé, je ne peux pas venir : je suis de mariage.

[https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/être_de](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_de)

Par contre, il ne donne pas la moindre référence sur cet usage. Pas de dictionnaire, rien. Sur une autre page, il précise que l'usage est "familier".

---

- Concernant l'origine de l'expression:

1- Il est probable que cette expression se soit bâtie sur le modèle de "*être de* corvée", "*être de* garde", "*être de* service" (ou même "être de la partie") etc...

Le CNTRL:

[être de... = être du même bord]

> Par extension *Participer à.* Être d'une fête, être du voyage; *être de la noce*.

2- Ou alors "être de la noce" -> "être de noce".

- **Concernant l'emploi de cette expression**:

Finalement, le CNTRL confirme l'existence de cette expression en français:

> Être de + subst. peut signifier également, selon le cont., « être de corvée ». **Être de noce**, être de courses. Quelle est cette tenue, monsieur Vatel? *êtes-vous d'enterrement*, ou la marée manque-t-elle?

Ce n'est donc pas un usage régional (mais je ne dirais pas que son usage est connu partout). Et ce dernier extrait, et cette mention dans le CNTRL semble infirmer la mention "familier" du Wiktionaire.